# Installing TV on metal studs

Tags: studs, metal, television, mount

So I tried installing my new Samsung 55" inch LED above the fireplace on an articulating mount (about 45 pounds on the TV) and found metal studs. I decided to open up the wall and install 2x4 wood blocking between the metal stud that was centre in the fireplace and one that was 16" away on centre. I ended up installing 2 of the 2x4, one at the top of the mount and one at the bottom. I then repaired the drywall wall and attached the mount to the blocking with 6 1/4" lag bolts. This is my first time hanging a TV and I am probably being paranoid but just wanted to check with some more expierenced people to determine if this will be strong enough.

Comment: how is the wood secured to the metal studs?

Comment: The metal studs faces each other so one end is in the groove and the other flush against flat part. I then screw them to the metal studs with #6 2" deck screws, two per each side of the block

Comment: sounds like total overkill to me, but better safe than sorry right?

Comment: Without the TV attached, pull on the bracket hard.  Does it feel secure? Does the wall board give in the process?